# Regular Expression Number Followed by Group Matching in Textmate

Tags: regex, textmate

Now I have few numbers for example

```
4723
4102
2160
8502
```

I want to add a `0` in the middle, to replace them as:

```
47023
41002
21060
85002
```

So what I did was matching:

```
^(\d{2})(\d{2})
```

replacing:

```
$10$2
```

But it doesn't give me correct result. Wondering how to escape the `0` in between `$1` and `$2`? Much Thanks.

Comment: What flavour of regex are you using (i.e. what language/tool are you using to match)?

Comment: Why do you even need a regex to do this? Why not just split and re-concatenate?

Comment: I am simply use regular expression matching function inside my Textmate.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the regex parser gets confused with `$10`. Try `${1}0${2}`. Test: http://regex101.com/r/xT3zT7

Comment: Try $0, rather than ${1}